# How to gitlab CI/CD with spring boot service that connect mysql kubernetes service

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kubernetes, gitlab

I am learning gitlab CI/CD and kubernetes, I am facing an issue.
I have a CI/CD pipelines for spring-boot services in gitlab that create container and then deploy to GKE.

Everything works fine but the service that connects mysql database.
It is quiet clear that since my service refers to the mysql host in kubernetes ( INTERNAL ) the build failed in gitlab.
I have no clue how to solve this, except to give an external IP to my mysql kubernetes service.
However when the service is deployed on GKE it should be better to access it from internal hostname.

How can I Go through this issue ? What is the correct way to implements CI/CD gitlab with a spring boot service that connects mysql kubernetes service ?

Thanks !